# asp.net order and GroupBy lists in a dictionary in a controller mvc3 class

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on an asp.net mvc3 application with linq2sql.

I have a List of SiteLog object type containing also for each object: A string named CLRExceptionType and a date named EntryDate. This List is included in a Dictionary:

```
private Dictionary<string, List<SiteLog>> dataBaseList = new Dictionary<string, List<SiteLog>>();
DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext("string1");
DataClasses1DataContext db2 = new DataClasses1DataContext("string2");
```

And I populate the vocabulary in the same controller in a function:

```
       private void CreateDictionary()
    {   
        dataBaseList.Add("db", db.SiteLogs.ToList());
        dataBaseList.Add("db2", db2.SiteLogs.ToList());
    }
```

So for each "Database" I have a list of Exception occurred.

Now I have to display on the view, for each database, the exception occurred grouped by exception and ordered by date.

So for example the output will be: Database1: 
Exception1 (22 times) last occurred: 22.10.1989 19:30
Exception2 (2 times) last occurredd 20.5.1980 14.50

Then suddenly the object is updated with a new entry with the name Exception2 so I have to display:
Exception2 (3 times) last occurredd 20.7.2011 9:00
Exception1 (22 times) last occurred: 22.10.1989 19:30

How can I achieve this using the groupby or any other solution in the controller?
I return the dictionary to the view.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var result =
  dataBaseList.GroupBy(x => x.Key)
              .SelectMany(x =>
                            x.SelectMany(n => n.Value
                                               .GroupBy(g => g.CLRExceptionType)
                                               .Select(g => new
                                                            {
                                                              DB = x.Key,
                                                              Exception = g.Key,
                                                              Count = g.Count(), 
                                                              LastOccured = 
                                                               g.Max(y =>
                                                                     y.EntryDate)
                                                            })))
              .OrderBy(x => x.DB)
              .ThenByDescending(x => x.LastOccured);
```

This groups your dictionary by the key (= database). Each group is then grouped by the exception type. For each such group an anonymous type is selected with all the data you want to display. SelectMany flattens the data from an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` to an `IEnumerable<T>`. The result is then ordered by the database and then by the last occurred date.
The result will be a list of anonymous type instance, each with the info you want to display.

Comment: I got an error on CLRExceptionType, it seems it does not see it:
Error 1 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,System.Collections.Generic.List<MvcLogs.SiteLog>>' does not contain a definition for 'CLRExceptionType' and no extension method 'CLRExceptionType' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,System.Collections.Generic.List<MvcLogs.SiteLog>>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Please try again. I changed the line with `SelectMany` from `x.GroupBy` to `x.Value.GroupBy`.

Comment: .OrderBy(y => y.DB)
              .ThenByDescending(y => y.LastOccured));
I have to change the x with the y or I got an error. Btw debugging it, it seems it takes only the values from one db, and not from the second one.. or it writes db also for the entries of the db2...
And how can I access the fields in the view? Seems doing a foreach and then item.ID item.Exception don't work and I have a Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'DB'

Comment: @Attila: Sorry, I missed copying a closing parenthesis in the line above `OrderBy`. Fixed.

Comment: @Atilla: If you want to return the grouped result from your method, you can't work with anonymous types and you need to create a class with those four properties and use `new YourClass {` instead of `new {`.

Comment: Ok I'll create a class, but I still have the problem that I only have values of the first db... result.DB is always the same even if I'm sure there are values from more than one db

Comment: Than there is some other problem in your code. I tested the code above and it returns results from both databases...

Comment: @Attila: See [here](http://pastebin.com/vzACKcAe). Paste this into [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net), choose `C# Program` in the language dropdown and check the result.

Comment: I've just a small problem left, The databases are not ordered by date.
The entries are correctly sorted, but not the databases.
So for example the first database can have the last occurence the 10th of september, but then the second database displayed can have the last date the 11th of september... I should display the databases according to the date of the last log of it.
How can I do this?

Comment: @Attila: Please create a new question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870038/asp-net-linq-groupby-and-orderby-on-dates-does-not-retrieve-the-expected-output
Created here