# Asp.net LINQ groupby and orderBy on dates does not retrieve the expected output

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on an asp.net mvc3 application with linq2sql.

I have a List of SiteLog object type containing also for each object: A string named CLRExceptionType and a date named EntryDate. This List is included in a Dictionary:

```
private Dictionary<string, List<SiteLog>> dataBaseList = new Dictionary<string, List<SiteLog>>();
DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext("string1");
DataClasses1DataContext db2 = new DataClasses1DataContext("string2");
```

And I populate the vocabulary in the same controller in a function:

```
   private void CreateDictionary()
{   
    dataBaseList.Add("db", db.SiteLogs.ToList());
    dataBaseList.Add("db2", db2.SiteLogs.ToList());
}
```

Then I have this Linq query:

```
var result =
dataBaseList.GroupBy(x => x.Key)
          .SelectMany(x =>
                        x.SelectMany(n => n.Value
                                           .GroupBy(g => g.CLRExceptionType)
                                           .Select(g => new
                                                        {
                                                          DB = x.Key,
                                                          Exception = g.Key,
                                                          Count = g.Count(), 
                                                          LastOccured = 
                                                           g.Max(y =>
                                                                 y.EntryDate)
                                                        })))
          .OrderBy(x => x.DB)
          .ThenByDescending(x => x.LastOccured);
```

That should give me the following output:

Database1:
Exception1 (22 times) last occurred: 22.10.1989 19:30
Exception2 (2 times) last occurredd 20.5.1980 14.50

Database2
Exception1 (22 times) last occurred: 21.10.1989 19:30
Exception2 (2 times) last occurredd 20.5.1980 14.50

Then suddenly the List is updated with a new entry in the database2 so I have to put this database on top:

Database2
Exception1 (1 times) last occurred: 29.07.2011 12.00
Exception1 (22 times) last occurred: 21.10.1989 19:30
Exception2 (2 times) last occurredd 20.5.1980 14.50

Database1:
Exception1 (22 times) last occurred: 22.10.1989 19:30
Exception2 (2 times) last occurredd 20.5.1980 14.50

So basically, I can order the logs in the database By date, but I cannot order the databases by the last date occurred on it, how can I solve this?
Viewcode (Index.cshtml):

```
<div id="results">

@{
    string firstTime = "";
}
 @foreach( var database in Model)
 {
       int currentCol = 0 ; 
        if (!(firstTime == database.DB))
        {
          <br style="clear:both" /><h3> @database.DB </h3>
                currentCol = 0;
        }

           <div class="logContainer" onclick="location.href='/logs/Details?databaseID=@database.DB&exceptionName=@database.Exception&exceptionsOccurred=@database.Count';">

                @if (database.Count > 999)
                {
                    <div class="counter-small"><b>@database.Count</b></div>
                }
                else
                { 
                <div class="counter"><b>@database.Count</b></div> 
                }
                <div class="exceptionName"> Exceptions of Type: @database.Exception</div>
                <div class="date">Siste: @database.LastOccurred</div>
         <hr />   </div>
     currentCol += 1;
          if (currentCol == 2) { //3 columns were displayed, switch row
    currentCol = 0;
    <br style="clear:both" />
}

     firstTime = database.DB; 
}

</div>
```

Tnx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to approach this would be to switch from L2SQL to L2Objects after you have the data then group again so you can sort:

```
var result = dataBaseList.GroupBy(x => x.Key)
          .SelectMany(...)
          .AsEnumerable()
          .GroupBy(x => x.DB)
          .OrderByDescending(g => g.Max(x => x.LastOccured));
```

This will give you a list of groups with `Key` of `DB`, in the order of the groups' last exception.

To consume these results, you would use nested foreach loops:

```
<div id="results">
  @foreach(var group in Model)
  {
    int currentCol = 0; 
    <br style="clear:both" />
    <h3> @group.Key </h3>

    @foreach(var database in group)
    {
      <div class="logContainer" onclick="location.href='/logs/Details?databaseID=@database.DB&exceptionName=@database.Exception&exceptionsOccurred=@database.Count';">

        @if (database.Count > 999)
        {
          <div class="counter-small"><b>@database.Count</b></div>
        }
        else
        { 
          <div class="counter"><b>@database.Count</b></div> 
        }
        <div class="exceptionName"> Exceptions of Type: @database.Exception</div>
        <div class="date">Siste: @database.LastOccurred</div>
        <hr />

      </div>

      currentCol += 1;
      if (currentCol == 2) { //3 columns were displayed, switch row
        currentCol = 0;
        <br style="clear:both" />
      }
    }
  }
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, the query might work without `AsEnumerable()`, but I expect it would be much harder for L2SQL to translate correctly.

Comment: I tried but i got this error in the view:
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'DB'
Line 20:             if (!(firstTime == database.DB))

Comment: Yeah, you will need to change your view because the structure of result is changing. The new structure is probably easier to work with since it's already grouped for you. Feel free to post the view code if you can't figure it out.

Comment: I posted it, cause I'm a bit lost

Comment: It does not work :(
I got an error on @Group.key, and if I delete it, I got no errors, but the results are displayed not in order :\

Comment: The order should come from the `OrderByDescending(...)` line - removing `@group.Key` wouldn't affect that. What type is `Model` in your view?

Comment: It is a Linq to Sql model, so I don't have the model code, but only the database table DataClasses1.dbml, do you know how can I get the view strongly typed?

Comment: You need to add a `@model Full.Name.Of.Type` declaration. However, to do this you will need to replace the anonymous type (`new { DB = ... }`) with a named type. The model type would then be `IGrouping<string, YourType>`.